# Python relative imports in a git submodule: avoiding "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, git-submodules

I have a Python package with the following structure and an empty `__init__.py` file:

```
my_package
|-- __init__.py
|-- module_a.py
|-- module_b.py
|-- tests
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_module_a.py
|   |-- test_module_b.py
```

Within `module_a.py` and the tests I import from `module_b.py` as follows (without a relative import):

```
from module_b import my_utility_function
```

When my current directory (VS Code) is `my_package`, this all works just fine. However, I want to use `my_package` as a git submodule in another program:

```
my_program
|-- main.py
|-- my_package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module_a.py
|   |-- module_b.py
|   |-- tests
|       |-- test_module_a.py
|       |-- test_module_b.py
```

In this `main.py` I *want* to use `my_package` like so:

```
from my_package.module_a import my_function
```

The problem is this only works if I change the import statement in `module_a.py` to a relative import:

```
from .module_b import my_utility_function
```

But now, when I'm developing within `my_package` I can't run my tests without getting the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

So I'm at an impasse: if `my_package` works for developing and testing, I can't use it in `my_program`. But if I use the relative imports so it works in `my_program`, I can't develop and test it independently.

I could add a `sys.path.append()` to `my_program/main.py` and then import `module_a` instead of `my_package.module_a` (this is the "solution" I've found on similar questions) but this seems hack-y and not portable. Furthermore, I'd like it to be clear that `module_a` comes from `my_package`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

there is a very elegant solution of this problem, which I have learned from the master David Beazley [here](https://speakerdeck.com/dabeaz/modules-and-packages-live-and-let-die?slide=53) and it would help in this case also.

I've simplified a bit, but I've done the following, where :

```
# module_a
__all__ = ["test_in_module_a"] # definition of *-import

def test_in_module_a():
    print("test_in_module_a")

# module_b
__all__ = ["test_in_module_b"] # definition of *-import

def test_in_module_a():
    print("test_in_module_b")

# __init__.py
from .module_a import *
from .module_b import *

__all__ = (module_a.__all__ + module_b.__all__) # attention, attention, must be tuple, otherwise explodes
# main.py 
from my_package import *

test_in_module_a()
test_in_module_b()

# Result:
# >>> test_in_module_a()
# >>> test_in_module_b()
```

As I understood your question, I would do it like this, because you only need to pay attention on your module imports `__all__` and the rest will be done in the `__init__.py`. In this manner you would be also in the position to extend your package without any further issues.

I hope to have been of some help.

Good luck :)